# Replace Hexadecimal values with another hexadecimal values in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, sed, hex

I am trying to replace a hex value in one of my files.

However, I am not sure how to write it back out in its normal form. I am not sure if the below is the right way to do it. I am changing the hex 25 to hex 15.

The file example_2018-02-02-14-51-47_US.txt is in UTF-8.

```
cat example_2018-02-02-14-51-47_US.txt | sed 's/\x25\x15/ /g' | od -x > example_2018-02-02-14-51-47_US_Convert.txt
```

Here is what the end of my example file looks like when I do xxd. I am trying to replace the hex 25 at the end with hex 15:

```
05ff020: a289 9585 a2a2 1ed3 f4c2 d7f5 f8d3 f1f3  ................
05ff030: e7c4 1e95 a493 931e d985 98a4 85a2 a396  ................
05ff040: 991e 95a4 9393 1e95 a493 931e 95a4 9393  ................
05ff050: 1ef2 f0f2 f2f2 f2f4 f0f4 f3f1 1ed2 d3e8  ................
05ff060: e6f8 f7f8 c2e6 c1d2 1ee2 8599 a589 8389  ................
05ff070: 9587 1ec2 9696 9240 9686 40c2 a4a2 8995  .......@..@.....
05ff080: 85a2 a21e c689 9985 1ec2 a4a2 8995 85a2  ................
05ff090: a240 d6a6 9585 99a2 1e95 a493 931e 95a4  .@..............
05ff0a0: 9393 1e95 a493 931e f0f0 f0f5 1ec9 d31e  ................
05ff0b0: f0f0 f0f0 f0f0 f0f0 f0f0 f0f0 f3f5 f825  ...............%
```

Comment: try `s/\x25/\x15/g`

Comment: When you do xxd?  So you're actually trying to replace values in a binary file, not 'hex characters', is that right?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to replace the actual hex values

Comment: `s/\x25/\x15/` works.  See my answer below, it shows that a minimal example of binary data in a file works with `s///` as written.  Something else is going on.  Is your file actually binary?  You have a `.txt` extension.

Comment: So you want to change an ascii '%' for a `NACK`? Is it always the last byte of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I ended up taking that worked.

```
tr '\045' '\025' < example_2018-02-02-14-51-47_US.txt > example_2018-02-02-14-51-47_US_replaced.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: now the question reflect changing a binary file, so I've changed the answer accordingly:

We can replace bytes in a binary file using \x notation directly.  I made a testfile:

```
$ echo -ne "\xf0\xf0\xf3\xf5\xf8\x25" > binfile
$ cat binfile | xxd 
00000000: f0f0 0c33 0c35 0c38 0c32 35              ...3.5.8.25
```

Ok, so, we just pipe this through `sed` and it works:

```
$ cat binfile | sed -e 's/\x25/\x15/g' > newbinfile
$ cat newbinfile | xxd
00000000: f0f0 f3f5 f815                           ......
```

Comment: I just added a sample of the hex printout and a clarification to the question